# Swift 3.0 Thread Class Target Does not Implement Selector

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, oop, macos-sierra

I declare a property for my thread like so:

```
let loggingThread = Thread.init(target: self, selector: Selector(("loggingThreadProcess:")), object: nil)

@objc func loggingThreadProcess(object: AnyObject?) {

}
```

But I am getting the this error:

> [NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement
>   selector (*** -[_SwiftValue loggingThreadProcess:])

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define it as:

```
let loggingThread = Thread.init(target: self, selector: #selector(loggingThreadProcess:), object: nil)
```

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Removed the colon from "loggingThreadProcess:", but effectively you were right @Michael. Also, I was trying to declare/define a thread instance property. Removed that and added code to create the thread when the user actually presses the logging button.